# The distribution of an estimator

Tags: estimation, normal-distribution

I was reading the Wikipedia article on Robust Statistics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics#Properties_of_M-estimators

What is meant by the distribution of an estimator, as used here,

> It can be shown that M-estimators are asymptotically normally
>   distributed, so that as long as their standard errors can be computed,
>   an approximate approach to inference is available. Since M-estimators
>   are normal only asymptotically, for small sample sizes it might be
>   appropriate to use an alternative approach to inference, such as the
>   bootstrap.

Comment: Since the value of an estimator is a function of the observed data, and the observed data is assumed to follow some distribution, it follows that the value of the estimator also follows some distribution.  As the sample size gets large, estimators in the class of "M-estimators" become distributed according to a Normal (also known as Gaussian) distribution.

Comment: @jbownam: that looks like an answer, especially the first two lines.

Comment: The wikipedia entry should read something like "...asymptotically normally distributed, *meaning that* so long as their standard errors can be *estimated*, an approximate approach to inference is available." The bit about the bootstrap being appropriate in small sample sizes misses the point; the bootstrap is an asymptotically-justified method, not an exact method.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I also liked the answers [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26396/expectation-of-an-estimator). As ocram and Nesp point out, an estimator is a function of random variables (called a statistic), and therefore a random variable itself.

Comment: To add to the comment above, as Michael Lavine writes in his [book](http://www.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/book.html), under the section entitled "The sampling distribution of an estimator", the sampling distribution of an estimator is both useful for assessing an estimator's accuracy and for comparing potential estimators based on their concentration about the true value.

Comment: As a bootstrapper I do not object to the suggestion to use bootstrap in small samples. The bootstrap often works well in small samples.  The reason small samples are mentioned is because you can't rely on the asymptotic normality when the sample size is small.  The bootstrap will approximate the sampling distribution for the m-estimator at the given fixed sample size. It is an approximate method and we say the bootstrap works if we can show consistency theoretically.

Comment: Requiring consistency does not rule out the possibility that a consistent bootstrap procedure provides a good approximate result in small samples.  Like almost any statistical technique the bootstrap will not perform well in very small samples.

Comment: @jbowman, following Henry, perhaps you should convert your comment to an answer. Then the OP can accept it, as it does answer the question & she has acknowledged that (& I can upvote it ;-) ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following Henry and Gung's advice in comments (thanks!)

Since the value of an estimator is a function of the observed data, and the observed data is assumed to follow some distribution, it follows that the value of the estimator also follows some distribution. As the sample size gets large, estimators in the class of "M-estimators" become distributed according to a Normal distribution, and one can use this fact, along with a little bit of hope (or bootstrapping) to develop approximate confidence intervals.

Comment: (+1) Good high-level description.